# How to append selected item of several ASP.NetRadioButtonList and display within a html Div using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a situation where I have three to four RadioButtonList on my web form and I want to display each selected items from these RadioButtonList within a HTML Div in this format **"A/B/C/D"**.

Here **A** is the item of RadioButtonList1, **B** of RadioButtonList2, **C** of RadioButtonList3 and **D** of RadioButtonList4.

I was able to display selected items within html Div, but the problem is I want to display selected item on every click event of RadioButtonList.

i.e. When I select item from RadioButtonList1 **"A"** gets displayed within DIV, then when I select **"B"** item from RadioButtonList2 **"A/B"** gets displayed similarly when I select **"C"** from RadioButtonList3 **"A/B/C"** gets displayed. Please guide me how can I achieve this-

**My aspx Page-**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var $radBtn = $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:radio');
            $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                var $radChecked = $('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:checked');
                $('#<%= RadioButtonList2.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                    var $rad1Checked = $('#<%= RadioButtonList2.ClientID %> input:checked');
                    $('#<%= RadioButtonList3.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                        var $rad2Checked = $('#<%= RadioButtonList3.ClientID %> input:checked');
                        $("#para").text('')
                    .append($radChecked.next().text() + "/" + $rad1Checked.next().text() + "/" + $rad2Checked.next().text());
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<div class="smallDiv">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>A1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A5</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>B1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B5</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem>C1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <p id="para">
        </p>
    </div>
```